# A file was included is a symlink or does not exist - Github Pages

Tags: github, bootstrap-4, jekyll, github-pages

I'm having a problem to build my site on GitHub Pages. I'm getting the following error message:

> Your site is having problems building: A file was included in
>   vendor/Magnific-Popup/website/index.html that is a symlink or does
>   not exist in your _includes directory. For more information, see
>   https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#file-is-a-symlink.

If I add '.nojekyll' file to the root directory of my repository, nothing is shown in my .io page. (404 not found is shown).

I've gone through some similar issue regarding this on stackoverflow and reddit, but nothing seems to solve my issue. So please don't mark it as duplicate.

Here is my [vendor/Magnific-Popup/website/index.html](https://github.com/kishan0725/kishan0725.github.io/blob/master/vendor/Magnific-Popup/website/index.html)

Link to my repo: https://github.com/kishan0725/kishan0725.github.io

It would be nice if you explained what needs to be changed/added instead of what and I'm not aware of jekyll.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Jekyll 3.8, you need to exclude the `vendor` directory in your config file if you've it defined:

```yaml
# _config.yml

exclude:
  - "something" # whatever that's already there..
  - "Gemfile"
  - "vendor/"
```

In Jekyll 4.0, it is always excluded by default.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't have any config file.

Comment: Okay. Can't really tell that since your repository doesn't contain the source files. You can try deleting the entire `vendor` directory from your project's index. To use javascript libraries, it is always better to include *built* versions in the production site.